I watched a television program between 1990-2000 forgot the name
I watched a television film (between 1990-2000), but forgot the name.
The story was about swans. After a storm, a man found five baby swans. He takes care of them and when they grow up they leave him. But they never forget and one day all of them come back. True story of love. Please help me to find the movie/ not sure it was movie or a five-episode drama.

Sounds slightly similar to "Fly Away Home". Anna Paquin moves in with her father Jeff Daniels. She finds baby geese with no parents. They won't know how to migrate without a "parent figure" showing them how to. So Anna and Jeff train the baby geese to follow Anna in a light aircraft (an ultralight, I believe) that is painted to look like a goose. She then leads them south when winter comes. I believe they return the following spring. Very sweet story!
(BTW I will delete this answer if it's completely off the mark. There are a lot of elements that don't match.)


WOW its amazing...Thanks man .....:P

Fantastic! Thank you for marking this as "the correct answer". I love this movie. I've seen it a few times. I cry every time.
